# c++ extern object array

Tags: c++, arrays, object, g++, extern

I am trying to create an extern object array, but I think I am having a linking problem. I have a class defined on class.hpp file, on the Declarations.cpp file I include the class header and I proceed to create an array of the class, then on my second header file I have the same array declared as extern, this header is to be included where I need to use it, then main_header.hpp file is used to initialize the extern array , so they can be used wherever main_header.hpp is included.

But I am getting:

> error: undefined Reference to "myArray" on main_header.hpp

The code below is the minimal code to reproduce the issue, in here I had omitted header guards and code that is not important.

this is my setup:

> class.hpp

```
class myClass
{
  //Class Declaration
};

/* end of file */
```

> Declarations.cpp

```
#include "class.hpp"

myClass myArray[4];

/* end of file */
```

> main_header.hpp

```
#include "class.hpp"

extern myClass *myArray;

/* end of file */
```

> main_header.cpp

```
#include "main_header.hpp"

void setup()
{
  for(uint8_t i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {
    myArray[i] = myClass();
    myArray[i].begin();
  }
}

/* end of file */
```

> main.cpp

```
#include "main_header.hpp"

void function()
{
  setup();
  myArray[0].test();
}

/* end of file */
```

How can I properly declare an extern object array??

Thanks in advance!

Cheche Romo

edit:
I am compiling with g++ on PSoC Creator.

edit2:

if in my Declarations.cpp I add

> int var = 0;

then on main_header.hpp I add

> extern int var;

an then on main cpp

> int a = var;

it shows me no error for var, only for myArray.

Comment: How did you compile the program?

Comment: I am compiling with g++ in PSoC Creator.

Comment: I solved it, there was an invisible unicode character on declarations file, I don't know why did the compiler didn't warned me. Sorry for this trash question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change main_header.hpp to be:

```
extern myClass myArray[];
```

Comment: I have already tested that, and it gives me the same error :(

Comment: You did link, declarations.obj into your final project output, right?

Comment: Yes it should be linked im compiling with g++ on PSoC creator, I mean im not sure how linking is done, but it is not the first time I use extern variables on this environment, but it is the first time I declare an extern object array.